# In BigQuery if every query creates a temporary table, is it possible to find out the name of that temporary table in a subsequent SQL statement?

Tags: google-bigquery

If every query creates a temporary table, is it possible to find out the name of that temporary table in a subsequent SQL statement?

Per https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data :

> All query results are saved to a table, which can be either persistent
>   or temporary:
>
> A temporary table is a randomly named table saved in a special
>   dataset; The table has a lifetime of approximately 24 hours. Temporary
>   tables are not available for sharing, and are not visible using any of
>   the standard list or other table manipulation methods.

For example:

```
/* query 1 */
select * from whatever;

/* query 2 */
select * from [temporary_table_that_just_got_created];
```

Comment: I'm trying to develop some queries, using the Squirrel SQL interface. It would be convenient if I didn't have to drop into a shell to run these queries through the API.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot determine that name from within BigQuery Web UI using BigQuery SQL
But, Yes, you can find it by looking in Query History
You should find you query in history list and expand it by clicking on it
Name you are looking for is under "Destination Table"

It is also possible to do this with BigQuery API and very useful in client applications

You should use [Jobs: get API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) and see configuration.query.destinationTable (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource)

Comment: I'm not using the Bigquery Web UI, I am using the Squirrel SQL interface with the starschema JDBC driver.

Comment: i think you missed to mention this in your question

Comment: I think first line in my answer - most likely covers your case. I would recommend to add Squirrel SQL related tag so someone might have better answer

Comment: It wouldn't have to be Squirrel, it could be another interface. Eventually I was going to send the queries using the bq command-line tool, but I just found out it only supports running one query at a time. And I just now found out that the BigQuery UI only supports sending one query at a time. That's a shame. I may have to rethink my plans. I'm used to Postgres and am finding BigQuery to be a little rudimentary in the SQL department.

Comment: If you will post separare question outlining your problem you might find the answer. Your current question is too specific and might be not the best representation of your plans. As I mentioned you can easily determine destination temporary table using BigQuery API. so in general you high levelidea looks doable

Comment: I'm really just trying to figure out some way to work around not being able to create a temporary table or otherwise store the result of one query for use in a subsequent query (using SQL, not the API). For example, I would like to avoid copy-and-pasting a big subquery I have that I want to use in a self-join.

Comment: current version/dialect of BigQuery SQL does not support this. API is the only way. Either your own application or client you use should implement this. It is what it is. Even though answer is negative for you  - you got it :o)

Comment: @EmeryLapinski - this answer should be accepted. It's correct.