# Extracting result from Google BigQuery to cloud storage golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am using the following GoLang package: https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery

My app runs in Google App Engine

If I have understood the documentation correctly it should be possible to extract the result of a job/query to Google Cloud Storage using a job. I don't think the documentation is very clear and was wondering if anyone has an example code or other help.

**TL:DR**

1. How do I get access to the temporary table when using Go Lang instead of command line.
2. How do I extract the result of my Bigquery to GCS

** EDIT **

**Solution i used**

I created a temporary table and set it as the *Dst* (Destination) for the Query result and created an export job with it.

```
dataset_result.Table(table_name).Create(ctx, bigquery.TableExpiration(time.Now().Add(1*time.Hour)))
```

Update 2018:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/issues/547

To get the table name:

```
q := client.Query(...)
job, err := q.Run(ctx)
// handle err
config, err := job.Config()
// handle err
tempTable := config.(*QueryConfig).Dst
```

Comment: This bottom solution would be dreamy to use, but as of 2022 Go 1.9, this won't compile: undeclared name: QueryConfig (compile) go-staticcheck

Comment: So this does not work?
> For future reference they have now (since Dec 2017) added the feature to access it directly: github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/issues/547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I extract the result of my BigQuery to GCS

You cannot directly write the results of a query to GCS. You first need to run the query, save the results to a permanent table, and then kick off an export job to GCS.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

> How do I get access to the temporary table when using Go Lang instead of command line.

You call use the jobs API, or look in the query history if using the web UI. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190055/in-bigquery-if-every-query-creates-a-temporary-table-is-it-possible-to-find-out) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get).

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#temporary_and_permanent_tables

Comment: Seems a bit weird that you cannot access the temporary table created by the Query result and store (/export) that to the GCS. Is it reasonable to do this instead of parsing and uploading the data myself regarding performance?

Comment: My result queries are between 1-5 mb

Comment: Weird or not, that's how it is I'm afraid. To export to GCS, you first need to write to a permanent table, then kick off an export job to GCS.

Comment: For future reference they have now (since Dec 2017) added the feature to access it directly: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/issues/547